# Twitter-Bootstrap area under navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to delete the area under the navbar? I used the "margin-bottom: 0" and it's not working correctly.
[image]

Comment: paste your code to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and show us

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18706/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add .container class to your .wide div

```
<div class="wide container">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/grassog/1b0m6ztx/

Comment: You're my heart, you're my soul! :D Thank you very much, have a good day!

Comment: @TomaszChwicewski didnt you want full width background just like navigation is and then fit content in container?

Answer (score 0):

use **clearfix** class with **wide** or just add `overflow: hidden;` in **.wide**  to set `h1` margin

```
<div class="wide clearfix">
   <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

or

```
.wide {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the content inside `wide` div with `<div class="container"></div>` to keep full width background image as it is in your screenshot.

```
<div class="wide">
  <div class="container">
     <h1>test</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/noey9gwf/)